# Minimise maximum distance from closest sensor: How to distribute x distance sensors in a N×M rectangle efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, position, distribution

I have been wondering how I can come up with a program that can show how sensors should be placed in a room, to minimise the distance between a randomly placed object and any one closest sensor. Something like how the dots on a dice seem to always be the most "uniformly arranged".

An example problem I was hoping the algorithm can solve is *How do I place 7 sensors in a 13x27 room to minimise the distance between an object and any of its closest sensors?*

I have a few very lengthy trial and error iterative methods in mind, but I was hoping for something a bit more elegant.
The method I tried was to literally try every possible sensor arrangement by modelling the room as a N×M array, and recording what is the maximum distance between a randomly placed object and the nearest sensor. Then, save and pick the arrangement with that produces the lowest maximum distance.
However, with larger rooms, this method quickly becomes too slow.
Moreover, it's kind of an "ugly" solution as well in my opinion.

Comment: Does it have to be optimal? Or would a "good enough" solution work for you?

Comment: (not convinced die 2, 3, 6 are optimal)(for a square room, 2 might be stacked on centre, 3 should be a non-degenerate triangle, 6 might do better if it looked like 5)

Comment: I think a "good enough" solution should be good enough!:) For now we are actually concerned with the "max distance deviation" b/w object and sensor, and I have a very long iterative code that kind of works to "trial and error" and select the configuration that has the least maximum obj-sensor deviation. (I think it works at least haha...) but the thing is that its a little slow and inelegant haha

Comment: @greybeard yea tbh im not sure of it myself. But actually, (strangely enough) we are not so concerned about the average obj-sensor distance but just the maximum one. Intuitively, the way the dots are arranged on a dice seemed to really ensure any one point on the dice is always relatively close to any one dot but Im trying to find articles to verify it haha.

Answer (score 1):

The [Metric k-center problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center) springs to mind:

Given a *metric graph*, the metric k-center problem is to find a set of *k* nodes (let's call these *center nodes*) which minimizes the distance from any node to a center node. A graph is metric if the edge weights form a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space):

- `w(x,y) = 0 if and only if x = y` (the distance from every node to itself is zero, and the distance between two unique nodes is non-zero.
- `w(x,y) = w(y,x)` (in an undirected simple graph, this always holds)
- `w(x,z) <= w(x,y) + w(y,z)` (going directly from `x` to `z` is at least as fast as traveling via another node )

There is a [simple 2-approximation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center#A_simple_greedy_algorithm) for this problem. 2-approximation means that the result the the algorithm gives you is *at worst* two times as bad as the optimal solution. For example, if in the optimal solution you can place the distance sensors such that any location is at most 2 meters away from a distance sensor, then in a worst case scenario the algorithm returns a solution where any location is at most 4 meters away from a distance sensor.

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Maintain an initially empty set `S`.
2. Add an arbitrary node to `S`.
3. Add the node furthest from any node currently in `S` to `S`.
4. Repeat step 3 until `S` contains `k` nodes.

At the end, `S` is a solution at most two times as bad as the optimal solution.

To use this algorithm for your problem, you first need to build the graph. If the room is an `N x M` grid, let every cell in the grid be a node and let there be an edge between any two cells that are adjacent in a horizontal, vertical or diagonal direction. Let the distance between the nodes be the euclidean distance  (straight line distance) between the cells in the grid (that is `1` for horizontal/vertical adjacency, and `sqrt(2)` for diagonal adjacency). Now run the algorithm above where `k` is the number of distance sensors you have.

### A note on the quality of this solution

The k-center problem is in general NP-hard, as per the linked article. This algorithm is made to work with an arbitrary graph. Since dealing with exponential running times is unrealistic, we have to compromise on solution quality instead, which is the reason for the approximation factor.

Given that there are some restrictions on what rooms look like (i.e. every node has at most 8 neighbors, for instance), it might be that there is an algorithm which is much better for your particular case. I'll try to see if I can find anything.

Furthermore, I seem to recall that it is impossible to find a polynomial algorithm with approximation ratio better than 2 (i.e. one that guarantees better results), but I can't remember where I read that. I'll see if I can find that too.

Comment: Wow thank you so so much and it is truly much appreciated! Ill definitely give it a good read and ill update you when/if I succesfully understand and implement it. Thank you thank you! Perhaps using some keywords in the article I can start doing more focused research as well as previously, everything I searched didnt yield much relevant results.

Comment: @JavierLam Glad I could help. Understanding why the approximation factor is 2 is a little bit tricky, and I don't think the proof in the Wikipedia article helps, to be honest. But you might be able to find a good explanation somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

(This seems to be a geometry question, rather, with an added *How do I make a machine handle the tedious part*. Trying to come up with the right question to ask, let's accumulate observations:)
(using a landscape monitor: calling the smallest dimension *N height*, the other one *M width*.)

- trivial cases:

  - ((less than one sensor); one sensor: place in the middle)
  - *N ≤ x×M*: place in the centres of *x* identical *N×M/x* rectangles
- symmetry:
  with an even number of sensors, I *expect* the optimum to be symmetrical about the shortest axis,
  with a multiple of four about any orthogonal axes:

  - correct(no, see below)/proof?
- points of interest:
  apparently, the corners of the rectangle deserve special attention
  starting from a square and four sensors,

  - optimal arrangement: at ¼ and ¾ of *N* and *M*, respectively
  - does adding a fifth sensor help?
    Placing it in the middle, one can try moving sensors in direction of the corners:
    increases distance from centres of sides (which has been maximum to begin with) immediately
    Placing it in the middle of one line, one can approach a pentagon config - **ah**:
    [Circles Covering Squares](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/circovsqu/) (see the six, nine, and twelve circle arrangements for surprises)
    [Prover code for *Worst-Case Optimal Covering of Rectangles by Disks*](https://github.com/phillip-keldenich/circlecover)

Comment: Erich Friedman has been linked before: [Fully cover a rectangle with minimum amount of fixed radius circles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719298)